# jQuery: Detach table rows then append back to same position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove/append table rows using jQuery's detach() method.  I'd rather use this method than jQuery's hide/show to keep certain css styles.   The detach function is tied to a checkbox that will hide any rows that contain "No".

The problem I am having is my table has sortable headers, and if I sort any column before I use this function, the table rows do not get put back into the right position.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tablerows;

    $('#indexTable tr').each(function(i) {
        $(this).data('initial-index', i);
    });

    $('#customSwitch1').change(function () {
        if (tablerows) {
            $(tablerows).appendTo('#indexTable').each(function(){
                var oldIndex = $(this).data('initial-index');
                $('#indexTable tr').eq(oldIndex).before(this);
            });
            tablerows = null;
        } else {
            tablerows = $('#indexTable tr:contains(No)').detach();
        }
    });

});
```

How can I put the rows back into the position before detachment, or even back to the position when the table is first loaded?

Comment: You are doing an awful lot of work to get around using the show/hide.   Instead of trying to put them in at the right index why not just add them at the bottom of the table and refire the sorting.  That'll force them into the right location.

Comment: Then you'd need to track the last applied sort so you can walk the table rows and insert at the appropriate location. Seems hide/show would be easier -- but I don't know your specific limitations.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I decided to just detach the rows, then reappend and sort.